# How to analyze multithreaded program throttle at high number of used threads

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm writing a simple program that calculates the number Pi according to [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm). Before I elaborate more on the problem, let me say that I'm testing my program (written in Java 8) on a 12-core CPU with 24 threads. According to `htop`, when running the tests, I have no load on the server, so that is out of the question.

However, I expect this to have near-linear speedup, when it starts to choke at high number of threads (let's say at >8, when it gets off the `y=x` line). At that point, the time in which the program executes for the same parameters with different numbers of threads is constant and speedup kind of tops at 10

Without too much concrete information, I would like to know how can I analyze where my program chokes. In other words, what are some must-do's when it comes to checking parallel programs' speedup.

Comment: It is impossible to say without having a look at you code, especially the way you accumulate your results. It could be that the reduction phase involves some expensive form of locking, and threads are getting more frequently blocked/ blocked for a longer time as their number increases.

Comment: A first hint could be to see if a lot of your threads are blocked in a few snpashots (which you could get with jvisualvm from your jdk).

Comment: You need to look at which resources are being shared.  Are you using the L3 cache very much or is all your data/code fitting comfortably into the 256 KB L2 cache?  BTW isn't most of the work serial, you could use multiple CPU to calculate this from scratch but it would be much more efficient to build each value based on the previous one.